# .NET Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

In my controller I have this method to update a model through a DTO that only contains a pair of its values in order to read a JSON that has only to update these two values.

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSituation(int id, SituationForApprovalDto SituationForApprovalDto)
{
    var situation = await _repo.GetSituation(id);
    _mapper.Map(SituationForApprovalDto, situation);
    return NoContent();
}
```

But the terminal depicts this when I start the app:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
SituationForApprovalDto -> Situation
Amaz.API.Dtos.SituationForApprovalDto -> Amaz.API.Models.Situation
   at lambda_method(Closure , SituationForApprovalDto , Situation , ResolutionContext )
   at Amaz.API.Controllers.SituationController.UpdateSituation(Int32 id, SituationForApprovalDto SituationForApprovalDto) in D:\Project6\Amaz\Amaz.API\Controllers\SituationController.cs:line 96
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

It is anything wrong with my method?

Comment: `AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.` means you are missing the mapping between source and destination type in your AutoMapper config

Comment: Where is the AutoMapper config in a .NET MCV project?

Comment: Assuming it is .NET Framework, you are talking about, take a look at this for understanding the automapper configuration - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924116/how-to-use-automapper-configuration-in-asp-net-mvc-controllers

If you are using dotnet core, check the documentation here - https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html#where-do-i-configure-automapper